# RPC to Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core

The research showed me that it is difficult to connect to Umbrel using the clear net. So I installed Bitcoin Core on my machine and synced the Blockchain. Now I get `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` as a result. I checked the bitcon.conf inside the main folder, I run bitcoin-qt

what I did in the bitcoin.conf

```
rpcuser=bitcoin
rpcpassword=pass
rpcport=8332
server=1
```

what else do I need or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I checked the bitcon.conf inside the main folder ... what did I do wrong?**

Clearly, you don't mean a folder named `main`, but you are being a little vague. One possibility is that Bitcoin core isn't looking for `bitcoin.conf` in the place you think it is.

On windows it typically looks in `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`

On Linux it typically looks in `$HOME/.bitcoin`

You can specify a particular path to a file using a command option such as

`-conf=/path/bitcoin.conf`

Comment: Thanks. I started using -conf and now it's working. So i will check where it is pulling it from normally.

Comment: Found, I just had to copy the conf file to the folder where the node saves the data, did it